# Gitlab Runner S3 Distributed Cache Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently trying to implement a shared s3 distributed cache for our Gitlab runners, but the configuration does not appear to be working as intended.

Below is my `config.toml` file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-1"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "XXX"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      AccessKey = "XXX"
      SecretKey = "XXX"
      BucketName = "XXX"
      BucketLocation = "eu-west-2"
      Insecure = false
```

And here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/<image>

services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  untracked: true
  key: $ECR_REPO
  paths:
    - "sbt-cache/ivy/cache"
    - "sbt-cache/boot"
    - "sbt-cache/sbtboot"

stages:
  - build

build:
  image: hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u151-2.12.4-1.1.1
  stage: build
  before_script: []
  script:
    - sbt test
```

The caching is working only on a local level, but when a job is picked up by a different runner it downloads all of the required data again. The S3 bucket is empty and the log from the pipeline job does not reference anything about the S3 bucket.

All AWS permissions are set up appropriately.

Gitlab Runner version: `12.1.0 (de7731dd)`

I tried many different configurations but none seem to work.

Comment: This may sound trivial, but did you restart the runner after modifying `config.toml`? Otherwise, everything looks good to me.

Comment: @DrewBlessing Yes, I've done it multiple times and ran a few debugging tests to ensure the new config was being used, which it was, but not the S3 caching bit though.

Answer (score 1):

S3 cache worked for me.

But I wanted to disable the shared cache and was also using `docker+machine` mode in gitlab runner. Feel free to make changes based on the `docker` mode you are using for gitlab runner. Below is the file for your reference

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "<redacted>"
  limit = 20
  url = "<redacted>"
  token = "<redacted>"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "<redacted>"
      BucketLocation = "us-east-1"
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 2
    IdleTime = 1800
    MaxBuilds = 10
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "<redacted>"
    MachineOptions = [<redacted>]
```

Regarding `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I followed the below comment to test the shared cache using S3. It worked fine. I could create files in the S3 bucket and fetch the content in the other stage as expected.

```
stages:
  - First
  - Second

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - workdir/

First:
  stage: First
  image:
    name: docker:latest
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  script:
  - mkdir -p workdir
  - echo "asdf" > workdir/r.txt


Second:
  stage: Second
  image: alpine
  script:
  - cat workdir/r.txt
```

Source:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22638#note_215163941